# Creating a matrix containing all combinations of contiguous districts in R

Tags: r, gis

I have geographical data for 1,032 precincts located within 123 voting districts.

For redistricting purposes, I need to create a matrix with every partition of the 1,032 precincts into 123 *contiguous* voting districts.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

The output should be a matrix with 1,032 rows, with each column representing a different combination of assignments (numbers 1 to 123) for these precincts.

Obviously, many of these combinations are unrealistic (ex.: districts made from one single precinct), but I need to create a matrix with all possible combinations *of adjacent precincts*.

**MY DATA (EXAMPLE WITH 5 PRECINCTS AND 3 DISTRICTS):**

1. I have the shapefiles and centroids for each precinct (may not be useful for this purpose, but just in case):

```
centroids <- data.frame(precinct=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                        lon=c(52.46795,52.40980,52.48036,52.41012,52.49236),
                        lat=c(13.32068,13.39792,13.34562,13.39955,13.35582))
```

2. I also have an adjacency list for each district:

```
adjlist_blocs <- list(c(2,3,4),
                      c(1,4),
                      c(1,4,5),
                      c(1,2,3,5),
                      c(3,4))

adjlist_blocs[[1]] # Where [[1]] refers to precinct number 1
[1] 2 3 4 # This means precinct number 1 is adjacent to precincts number 2, 3 and 4

adjlist_blocs[[2]]
[1] 1 4

adjlist_blocs[[3]]
[1] 1 4 5

adjlist_blocs[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 5

adjlist_blocs[[5]]
[1] 3 4
```

So in this example, the output would be a matrix with 5 rows (for 5 precincts) and columns encompassing all possible combinations of voting districts assignments (for instance, 3 voting districts) for adjacent precincts.

Something like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Precinct Nb     |   District Nb    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

This would mean that precincts 1 and 2 are in voting district #1, precincts 3 and 4 are in voting district #2, and that district #3 is only made of precinct number 5. This is just one of all possible combinations for these precincts given adjacency.

How can I create a matrix with all possible combinations of adjacent districts? Can R deal with the very high number of combinations that will be generated in the first place (for 1,032 precincts in 123 districts)? Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: What would be your expected output for given example?

Comment: @RonakShah I can't compute it unfortunately (that's why I'm writing this post), but in this case the output should be a matrix with 5 rows and all columns being different combinations of clustering for adjacent precincts (ex.: in 3 voting districts). Just edited the original post to clarify this. Any idea?

Comment: Could you clarify what the 5 members of the `adjacently list for each district` represents?    For example, what does the 1 in  `adjlist_blocs[[1]]` refer to?  Are 2 and 3 precinct numbers?

Comment: @WaltS The 5 members of that list represent the 5 precincts. adjlist_blocs[[1]] refers to the first element, so the first of these precincts (precinct number 1), and the content indicates which other precincts precinct number 1 is adjacent to (here, precincts 2 and 3). Hope this helps---thanks for this opportunity to clarify things.

Comment: It seems that the adjacency matrix should be symmetric .  Some members  are symmetric but not all.  For example,  [[1]] contains 2 and 3.  [[2]] and [[3]] contain 1 so they're symmetric but [[4]] includes 1, 2, 3 but [[1] and  [2]]  don't include 4.

Comment: @WaltS Absolutely---wrote this example too quickly, just corrected it to make it symmetric, thanks!